# Android Studio - Auto Import won't work even after 'fixing' the problem

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

**Straight forward ->** The Auto import function won't work on my Android Studio. 
Example: I declare a variable '*Button btn*' and I get no option to auto import (ALT+Enter) the Button library.

I have tried by going to Settings->General->Auto Import and changed the settings to this:
[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chG9Y.png)

It still ain't working. So I tried to Invalidate caches/restart, still not working.

I have been searching for help all day, without really finding any helpful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the value of the option **Insert imports on paste** to **Ask** instead of *All*. It should normally ask you to import new librairies that you need to have.